# Proxy error: Could not proxy request (DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, proxy, create-react-app

I have a React app that I generated using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). In the package.json file I have

```
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/google": {
      "target": "https://localhost:8008"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "https://localhost:8008"
    }
  },
```

The app runs fine until I make a call to one of the above proxied URLs. Wherein I then get for example

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/google from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:8008 (DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT).
```

I generated certificates with these commands

```
openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key localhost.key -out localhost.cert -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost
```

In my Node.js app, I'm using those certs as follows

```
    sslOptions = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./config/localhost.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/localhost.cert'),
      requestCert: false,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    };

  https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(serverStartMessage);
  });
```

Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: You created https server with the self-signed certificate ./config/localhost.cert and .key and you connect to it from your local https client and the client gives this error DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT, right?

Comment: @Oleg that is all correct.

Comment: Then you need to make the server certificate trusted on your client. Since it is self-signed you need to add it to the trusted list on the client. Alternatively you can disable trust verification on the client but this is not secure.

Comment: @Oleg how do make the front-end React App trust a self signed cert that I'm using for development?